Freeradius Access during business hours and business days
How to do authentication in Freeradius only during business hours and on business days. I thought it could be done through Policy.d by writing a policy. But I don't understand how to do it. I tried to do this
Work_Hours {
        if (hour >= 12 && hour < 20) {
            update control {
                Auth-Type := "Accept"
            }
        } else {
            update control {
                Auth-Type := "Reject"
            }
        }
}

It does not work.
I want to create groups in AD Samba ACL_Allow_24, ACL_Allow_Workhours. People from these AD groups will be allowed in constantly and only during business hours. How to do it?
